# Using session in the CSS Declaration

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to pass in the css file name to my razor page but I'm having difficulty getting the session to take.

Here is the line I have:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/epp.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I need to pass in 'epp' as a `Session["Css"]` but I haven't figured out how to do this.

I have tried:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/@HttpContext.Current.Session["Css"].ToString().css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

but that wasn't working.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You need to build the url "by hand" (with `string.Format` or with string concenation) for the `Url.Content` argument

```
<link href="@Url.Content(string.Format("~/Content/{0}.css", HttpContext.Current.Session["Css"]))" 
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to do something like this:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/" + HttpContext.Current.Session["Css"] + ".css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```